# Flask-Admin - Inline Model not working with field named something other than 'id'

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I am looking at inline models and have been testing out the example here:

https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/tree/master/examples/sqla-inline

I have noticed that if the primary key field of the LocationImage model/table is renamed to something other than ID, then the after_delete handler does not get triggered.

So this works

```
class LocationImage(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    alt = db.Column(db.Unicode(128))
    path = db.Column(db.String(64))
    location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Location.id))
    location = db.relation(Location, backref='images')

@event.listens_for(LocationImage, 'after_delete')
def _handle_image_delete(mapper, conn, target):
    try:
        if target.path:
            os.remove(op.join(base_path, target.path))
    except:
        pass
```

But if I rename the id column like so,

```
image_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Then _handle_image_delete does not get called.

I cannot fathom where this field is specified and how to make it work with a PK named something other than 'id'.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [field_list.html](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/examples/sqla-inline/templates/field_list.html) a hidden field is rendered for the primary key. You need to change it to output your renamed field `{{ field.form.image_id }}`.

```
{% import 'admin/model/inline_list_base.html' as base with context %}

{% macro render_field(field) %}
  {% set model = field.object_data %}
  {% if model and model.path %}
    {{ field.form.image_id }}
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=model.path) }}" style="max-width: 300px;"></img>
  {% else %}
    {{ field }}
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{{ base.render_inline_fields(field, template, render_field) }}
```

Comment: That was it! I saw that 'id' field but did not realise it was referring to the image id! Thank you!